# Can a 4/0 al wire be used for the neutral conductor on 200amp service?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, wire

Upgrading my house to 200 amp service. I can get a really good deal on some 4/0 al wire, so was wondering if there would be any reason I couldn't / shouldn't use 4/0 gauge for the neutral as well.

Comment: If 4/0 is legal for the hots, it's legal for the neutral.

Comment: I assumed so. The inspector said to use 4/0 for the hot and 2/0 for the neutral, but I was gifted almost 100' of 4/0 al so I was hoping to use it for the neutral as well. Thanks for the info Harper!!!!!

Comment: No problem going larger than required.   Harp is right (who am I to say! He knows a lot more about this than me!).  But this is an easy answer.

Comment: Do you know what *insulation type* this 4/0 wire uses?  (I'm concerned that it's single-rated USE(-2) which isn't legal for use indoors *at all*, not even inside conduit)

Comment: The guy I can get it from said it was left over URD from a job he did.

Comment: @roasthead -- can you get us the exact information on the wire/insulation type then please? Some URD is single-rated USE-2, other stuff is tri-rated RHH/RHW-2/USE-2, and the distinction *matters* here, especially if you're using it between meter and panel, or in an overhead service mast...

Comment: So....I think that deal fell through. Guy said he'd have to get back with me on whether or not he needed the wire. I messaged him a couple times asking for the exact specs but haven't heard anything back in hours.....so I'm chalking it up as a no-go!!!!!! Just gonna get some 4-4-2  SEU and call it a day.

Comment: @roasthead -- before you buy the cable, have you considered using a meter-main and feeder instead, due to the NEC 2020 first-responder disconnect requirements?

Comment: I asked the inspector about that....he said it wasn't required yet.  When I wire up my new breaker panel I'm going to separate the grounds and neutrals (still bonded though) so if I am required to install a disconnect or decide to do so before that, it'll be ready to convert to a sub-panel easily.